# Get records from two table in relation many to many

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

I have two table in relation many to many

```
public class Repertoire {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;
    private Integer dayWeek;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "repertoire_seance",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "repertoire_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "seance_id")}
    )
    List<Seance> seances = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and

```
    public class Seance {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer id;

    private java.time.LocalTime displayTime;

    @ManyToOne
    private Film film;

    @Column(length=127)
    private String kind;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private Hall hall;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "reservationSeance")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Reservation> reservations = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Hibernate create linked tabel repertoire_seance is posible get seances by seancesId and repertoire.dayWeek using spring data (JpaRepository) something like that findBySeanceIdAndRepertoireDayWeek()?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by writing an HQL.

It would look something like this:

```
select s from Repertoire r inner join r.seances s where r.dayWeek ="Your Value" and s.id = "Your Id Value"
```